# How can I skip one line in 'for' cycle?

Tags: python, loops

I have an input file, which contains lines like `'+    6    5'` (operator, four spaces, integer, four spaces, integer). I need to make an output file, which contains results of an operation (from `'+    6    5'` to `'11'`). All results should be separated by `','`.
How can make it elegantly not to add `','` in the last iteration of the loop (without moving the last iteration out of the loop)?

```py
input = open("/Users/aleksandrdudakov/Downloads/input_file.txt", "r")
output = open("/Users/aleksandrdudakov/Downloads/output_file.txt", "w")
data = input.readlines()
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    s = data[i]
    l = s.split(sep='    ')
    if l[0] == '+': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) + int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '-': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) - int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '*': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) * int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '//': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) // int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '%': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) % int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '**': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) ** int(l[2])))
    output.write(',')
i += 1
s = data[i]
l = s.split(sep='    ')
output.write(str(int(l[1]) // int(l[2])))

input.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: you can simply add the if condition to check whether it is the last item/line of your inputs. If not then add ',' - otherwise not adding it.

Answer (score 0):

As DrakeLiam mentions, you can either add a check of whether you're at the beginning of the loop and skip prepending the comma, or add a check of whether you're at the end of the loop and skip appending the comma.

```
output = open("/Users/aleksandrdudakov/Downloads/output_file.txt", "w")
data = input.readlines()
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i > 0:
        output.write(',')
    s = data[i]
    l = s.split(sep='    ')
    if l[0] == '+': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) + int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '-': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) - int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '*': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) * int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '//': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) // int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '%': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) % int(l[2])))
    if l[0] == '**': 
        output.write(str(int(l[1]) ** int(l[2])))

input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `print` with parameter `sep` (and `file`):

```py
def calc(line):
    op, x, y = line.rstrip('\n').split()
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    output = 'error' # default; if no pattern is matched, this will be printed
    if op == '+': output = x + y # or, match .. case for python 3.10+
    if op == '-': output = x - y
    if op == '*': output = x * y
    if op == '//': output = x // y
    if op == '**': output = x ** y
    return str(output)

with open("test.txt", "r") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as g:
    print(*map(calc, f), sep=',', file=g)
```

`test.txt`:

```
+ 1 2
* 2 3
// 4 2
? 1 1
** 2 3
```

`output.txt`:

```
3,6,2,error,8
```